# Using Mongoose Schema in multiple routes with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose & Express. I'm quite new to nodejs.

In my **routes/index.js**, I have a userDataSchema :

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userDataSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  username_lower: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
}, {collection: 'user'});

var UserData = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);
```

It works perfectly fine in that index.js file. 
I would like to use that same Schema without getting an error, in connexion.js file.

I have tried in **index.js**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);
```

in **connexion.js**

```
var UserData = require('./index.js');
```

And then I use my UserData in connexion.js.
That does not display any error, but my page is loading forever, whatever the page.

**So my question is how could I use that same Schema in multiple files of the routes folder ?**

I can make it work by creating a new Schema with another name : "UserDatas" **in connexion.js** instead of "UserData" in **index.js** (in this case I do not use exports neither require ./index.js)

```
var userDataSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    username_lower: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
  }, {collection: 'user'});

  var UserData = mongoose.model('UserDatas', userDataSchema);
```

*But I am not sure if it is the right way to do ?*

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file where you define the user model should look somewhat like the following:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

It is in a folder called models.
Assuming that index.js in is the same directory as the models folder, you can use it in index.js with

```
var User = require("./models/user");
```

Hope this helps!

And it is maybe not the best idea to put a model definition into a file that is located in the routes directory. Ideally you'll have a separate folder for routes and models to structure your files.

Comment: Exactly what Baha did in his project and so I did it and it worked, thanks a lot! :) Now the model is defined outside the routes, in an external file in the model folder, is it the right way (I did not get the "it is not the best idea" part ?)

Comment: As I'm not too experienced with web development myself, I can't really tell if it is the "right" way. I just know from programming in other languages that separating your code and sorting files that belong together into folders is great for a good understanding of the code.

Comment: Oh okay, then you meant that using a separate model is definitely a good thing, right ? Because for me it solves my problem + makes my code cleaner!

Comment: That's what I meant to say, yes!

Answer (score 1):

**you need to use new mongoose.Schema not new Schema,** 
 **so try this code**

```
const userDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
username_lower: String,
email: String,
password: String
}, {collection: 'user'});

const UserData = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);
module.exports = UserData;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello Baha :) Thank you for your answer and for joining stackoverflow. I updated my post, I already had mongoose.schema.

Comment: Thanks for your response Julien can you provide the code you used to retrieve something from mongo ...

Comment: You're welcome and thanks to you :) Can you please check my edited answer, do you think renaming the model is the correct way to do ?

Comment: That's not the perfect way to do it ... you can check this repo and look at how models controllers are made! https://github.com/bahachammakhi/hope-api   hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I will check that right now and come back to you

Comment: Okey waiting for you

Comment: Thank you so much Baha, I created a model for my UserData Schema, as you did in your project. I am quite new to nodejs and never used MVC with nodejs before, only with PHP. Now it works perfectly I use the same model in my index.js or connexion.js =)

Comment: Thank you too you can close this question then I hope that project will help you learning nodejs star it if you want have a nice day

Comment: Thank you so much I will take a look at it sometimes :) Have a nice day too!